# Results in cardinal arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What are some of the most advenced results in cardinal arithmetic?
For the sake of discussion, I'm not intrested in consistency Results (e.g: "It's consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$").
A good example of what I search for is Silver's theorem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of modern set theory has roughly had the theme, "Nothing about cardinal arithmetic can be proved in ZFC." My favorite source of **counterexamples** to this idea is [*PCF (**p**ossible **c**o**f**inalities) theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCF_theory).  This was invented by Shelah, and used by him and others to prove a number of ZFC-results; see also [this review of Shelah's book on cardinal arithmetic](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1996-33-03/S0273-0979-96-00673-8/S0273-0979-96-00673-8.pdf).

One of the most famous of these is the following statement: $$\mbox{If $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit, then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$}.$$ It is not currently known whether this is sharp, and indeed Shelah is on record as asking ["Why the hell is it four?"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0102056.pdf).

Comment: Are there any more results like this? or this+silver are the only strong results known?

Comment: @YfYf If you google around for PCF theory, you'll find **lots** of statements in a similar vein. Or, look at Shelah's book.

Comment: ok, i will, thanks.

Comment: How difficult is that proof? Could it be presented in a 90 minute seminar?

Comment: @Mingus It's extremely difficult, and absolutely not, respectively - unless your audience already knows some PCF theory.