# Cofinality as an axiom?

Tags: cardinals, axioms

If one wanted an axiomatisation of set/class theory in which cardinals became tame and "boring" by imposing an axiom that made all cardinals act "essentially" like the infinities we are familiar with $\omega$ and $\aleph_1$ what is the best choice of axiom.

Obviously GCH is a candidate because it enables us to evaluate cardinal exponentiation. But even GCH is a bit weak when it comes to taming the infinite cardinals, for example we still have regular and singular cardinals, and cofinality still plays a role in calculations.

My question is has anyone explored stronger axioms than GCH which are still "natural" and which further constrain the cardinals. In particular if we took $cf(\kappa)=\kappa$ for every infinite ordinal would that imply GCH and eliminate cofinality as a key concept from set theory.

Comment: Surely you mean $cf(\kappa) = \kappa$ for every infinite *cardinal*.

Answer (score 1):

$cf(\kappa)=\kappa$ for every *ordinal* (even every *limit ordinal*) is clearly false - think about $\omega+\omega$.

Even if we look at cardinals, it's *still* false: consider $\aleph_\omega$, the limit of the sequence $\aleph_0,\aleph_1, \aleph_2, ...$. This is uncountable but has cofinality $\omega$. The existence of $\aleph_\omega$ is provable in ZFC, the key being the axiom of replacement.

So in a sense yes, your proposal would eliminate cofinality as a key concept from set theory.

In order to have a good set theory, you need to have singular cardinals. The fact that they have complicated properties should be viewed as a positive, not a negative: the universe of sets is richer for having singular cardinals in it.

Also, if we're only willing to talk about the $\aleph_n$s then we'll lose theorems like  ["If $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087918/results-in-cardinal-arithmetic/2088014#2088014) Life just wouldn't be the same.

Comment: Thanks very much, they are good points. I greatly admire the efforts of logicians and set theorists over the last 150 years, and recognise working with a loose axiomatisation like ZFC makes it all a lot more fun and interesting. I am just interested in whether anyone has looked at stronger axiomatisations than the usual ZFC+GCH with the intent of "locking down" set/class theory so it has much fewer loose ends from a mathematical perspective (eg. Souslin lines, quasi-categories, set class divide).

Comment: @MarkKortink People have of course looked at this. The axiom V=L tends to settle every reasonable question about cardinal arithmetic, but contradicts large cardinals. MM isn't as all-settling but does answer lots of questions (e.g. CH). But I really think you're underestimating the value of variety here. Over time there has been a shift towards interest in the *collection of models* of ZFC; in the same way that the collection of groups has lots of cool variety because the group axioms aren't too strong, the "weakness" of the ZFC axioms leads to the collection of models being quite interesting.

Comment: @MarkKortink Incidentally, if you're looking for "practically-complete" theories which *are* compatible with large cardinals, check out **inner model theory**, and in particular Woodin's **ultimate $L$ program**.

Comment: Thanks, will do :)